# LLVM: Does the order of basic blocks matter?

Tags: c, llvm

I am writing my own programming language, and have the following source code:

```
if false {
  # do nothing
}
else {
  # do nothing
}

return 0
```

My compiler currently outputs the following LLVM IR:

```
; ModuleID = 'tmp.sk'
source_filename = "tmp.sk"

define i64 @main() {
entry:
  br i1 false, label %if_true, label %if_false

if_true:                                          ; preds = %entry
  br label %end

end:                                              ; preds = %if_false, %if_true
  ret i64 0

if_false:                                         ; preds = %entry
  br label %end
}
```

Notice the order of the basic blocks:

```
entry
if_true
end
if_false
```

But in my source code, the logical progression has the `end` and `if_false` swapped. From what I know about basic blocks, they must end in a terminator instruction, such as `ret` or `br`. This means that there shouldn't be any issue with blocks bleeding together.

My question is, are there any other concerns I am not addressing, or is this perfectly fine, albiet less human readable LLVM IR?

(I am using the LLVM-C API, if that is of any use.)

Comment: Well, do you understand the syntax of the `br` instruction it's emitting? Does the logic make sense, given that?

Comment: Yes, the branching behaviour is correct. The IR it is generating should be correct as well. I say "should" because I am curious if there are any potential corner cases where having blocks out of order may cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of basic blocks is arbitrary. Even more, compiler could rearrange them to make fallthrough as many branches as possible.